# QCalendarWidget - How to Highlight Dates

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a `QList<QDate>` with dates to events, and I want to highlight those dates on a `QCalendarWidget`, hopefully, with an image, can be changing the cell color.

I'm probably making a novice mistake in my code...

This code that I modified from ([Here](http://appearstupid.blogspot.cl/2008/06/highlight-todays-date-in.html)) should make the `QCalendarWidget` paint the dates with a red border, but it doesn't...

**mainwindor.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    m_manager = new CalendarManager(ui->calendarWidget);

    setupConnections();

    on_calendarWidget_clicked(QDate::currentDate());
}

/* GUI button behavior */
```

**calendarmanager.h**

```
#ifndef CALENDARMANAGER_H
#define CALENDARMANAGER_H

#include <QCalendarWidget>

#include <QStringList>
#include <QBrush>
#include <QColor>
#include <QFile>
#include <QList>
#include <QDate>
#include <QPen>

class CalendarManager : public QCalendarWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QColor color READ getColor WRITE setColor)

public:
    CalendarManager(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~CalendarManager();

    void setColor(const QColor &color);
    QColor getColor() const;

protected:
    virtual void paintCell(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect, const QDate &date) const;

private:
    struct calendarEvent
    {
        QDate date;
        QString name;
    };

    QList<calendarEvent> m_events;
    QList<QDate> m_dates;

    QPen m_outlinePen;
    QBrush m_transparentBrush;

    void getDates();
};

#endif // CALENDARMANAGER_H
```

**calendarmanager.cpp**

```
#include <QPainter>

#include "calendarmanager.h"

CalendarManager::CalendarManager(QWidget *parent)
    : QCalendarWidget(parent)
{
    m_outlinePen.setColor(Qt::red);
    m_transparentBrush.setColor(Qt::transparent);

    getDates();
}

CalendarManager::~CalendarManager()
{

}

void CalendarManager::setColor(const QColor &color)
{
    m_outlinePen.setColor(color);
}

QColor CalendarManager::getColor() const
{
    return ( m_outlinePen.color() );
}

void CalendarManager::paintCell(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect, const QDate &date) const
{
    QCalendarWidget::paintCell(painter, rect, date);

    if( m_dates.contains(date) ) {
        painter->setPen(m_outlinePen);
        painter->setBrush(m_transparentBrush);
        painter->drawRect(rect.adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1));
    }
}

void CalendarManager::getDates()
{
    QFile file("/data/events.csv");
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        //Error code
    }

    QList<QByteArray> wordList;

    QDate date;
    QString name;
    calendarEvent e;

    while(!file.atEnd()) {
        QByteArray line = file.readLine();
        wordList = line.split(',');

        date = QDate::fromString( wordList.first(), "dd/MM/yyyy" );
        name = wordList.last();

        e.date = date;
        e.name = name;

        m_events.append(e);
        m_dates.append(date);
    }

    file.close();
}
```

Comment: what is on_calendarWidget_clicked?

Comment: Why do you do this: `m_manager = new CalendarManager (ui-> calendarWidget);`?

Comment: `on_calendarWidget_clicked`, is a response to a button, to set the calendar date to the current date whenever you open the stacked widget page.

Comment: I passed the manager the actual widget as a parent... was I not supposed to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when creating `m_manager` you are not including this in the GUI, even if you pass the parent `ui->calendarWidget`.

What you should do is promote your GUI to use that widget, that you can easily from the design view.

1. Right click on calendarWidget and select `Promote to`:

[image]

2. Select as **Base Class** a `QCalendarWidget`, **Promoted Class Name**: `CalendarManager` and **Header File**: `calendarmanager.h`

[image]

3. Press Add and Promoted:

[image]

Screenshot of output:

[image]

*Note*: it is not necessary to create `m_manager`, if we look at `ui->calendarwidget` is an instance of `CalendarManager`.

Comment: It should work, I mean, I really see it working, but it doesn't... (could the stacked widget mess anything up? Or the file reading? Let me check

Comment: Yes, file reading has a problem, that works perfectly, thanks

Comment: I recommend you use an `absolute path` instead of `relative path`, or use `QFileDialog: getOpenFileName()`

Comment: Will look at it, thanks, but hte problem is in how the string is converted to a date, i think, because that's where it seems to fail, and it uses a application file, not something the user should select... for debug that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: My file has the following format: `22/07/2017,"hola"`

Comment: mine was: 22/07/2017,EVENT

Comment: Nice, Greetings From Chile!

Comment: Hey all, using this I have a problem (qt 5.13), the drawing is done only when I click on the promoted QCalendarWidget, tried using update() and redraw(), from inside the derived class or from the parent code, but to no avail.